# html popup background is overlapping with background in mobile device

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I have created a popup for menu section of the home page. you can see the menu section when u scroll the page, below the reservation button. The popup is working correctly on the desktop. When I open the same page on the mobile device and click the menu the popup is overlapping with the background.

I am unable to find the error. When I open the page on the desktop it opens perfectly. I want the page to open same on the mobile device as on desktop

URL:
https://theparlour21.se/

Following is the CSS I used to create modal:

```
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: #000;
}
.modal-content {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    color: #d4d2d2 !important;
    border: 1px solid #451d22!important;
    padding: 0 20px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 560px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `z-index:99999;` property in your  `.modal class`